# Membase logical cache sections

Tags: c#, caching, membase

Does membase has a notion of cache sections?

such as: 
Users cache, News cahce, Item cache etc.

When I am storing users, I want to be able to store and read from the cache section. Likewise for Items store and read from Item cache.

Is this supported?

does .net client supports this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to store items in different cache contexts? Membase support the idea of a bucket and you can create a user bucket, a news bucket, and an item bucket. From you client you would then have to connect to each bucket with a separate connection.

Comment: Thanks. you wanna answer with that , and i ll mark it.

Comment: Just added that below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Membase supports the idea of a bucket and you can create a user bucket, a news bucket, and an item bucket. From you client you would then have to connect to each bucket with a separate connection.